# the moviedb url ending point not working?

Tags: json, postman, themoviedb-api

I am developing android movie app using themoviedb but when I call movies json ending point I am getting this error from postman {
    "status_code": 7,
    "status_message": "Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key."
}

below my ending point
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id?api_key=45bf6592c14a965b33549f4cc7e6c664=&language=en-US

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually pass a movie id in order to get a valid response back. As per the docs, test your api key this way:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key={api_key}&callback=test
```

Or in your case, with your api key you have provided:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=45bf6592c14a965b33549f4cc7e6c664&callback=test
```

More information at the link below:

https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/json-and-jsonp